# How to close a bootstrap modal manually (angular)?

Tags: angular-forms, angular-bootstrap

I am building a sign up form inside a bootstrap modal.
After the submission (button press) the modal does not close.
I can't use the data-dismiss attribute because then the modal would be closed before the data is submitted for registration on the server side.
Was trying to solve it using ngbactivemodal but it seems something I did during the implementation of bootstrap-angular is not right.
Attached is:

The register component.ts-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { matchOtherValidator } from '../match-other-validator';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map,take,switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { RegisterService } from '../register.service';
import {NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'

const tzAsyncValidator = (http: HttpClient) => (c: FormControl) => {
  console.log(c.parent);
  if (!c || String(c.value).length === 0) {
    console.log("!c|| String (c.value).length ===0")
    return of(null);

  }

   return c.valueChanges.pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap(_ =>
      http.get('http://localhost:4000/userIds/' + String(c.value))
        .pipe(
          map((ids: any[]) => {
            console.log(ids);
            if (ids.length === 1) {
              return { exists: true }
            }
            if (ids.length === 0) {
              return null;
            }
          }))
    ))
}






@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  public newUser;
  public verification=false;
  public newUser2;
  public finalUser;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public RS:RegisterService, private activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.newUser = new FormGroup({
      Tz: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(9), Validators.maxLength(9)], [tzAsyncValidator(this.http)]),
      Email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      PW: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$')]),
      PWVerification: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$'), matchOtherValidator('PW')])
    })
  }
  onSubmit(){
    this.verification=true;
    this.newUser2= new FormGroup({
      City: new FormControl ('',Validators.required),
      Street: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      FirstName: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      LastName: new FormControl('',Validators.required)
    })

  }


  onSubmit2(){
    this.finalUser=({...this.newUser.value,...this.newUser2.value});
    this.RS.RegisterUser(this.finalUser)
    .subscribe(()=>{
      console.log(this.activeModal);
      this.activeModal.close();
})
  }
}
```

register component html-

```
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" >
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Sign Up!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form [formGroup]="newUser" (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()' *ngIf="verification!=true">
          <label>ID</label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Your ID" formControlName="Tz">
          <br>
          <label>Email</label>
          <br>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email" formControlName="Email">
          <br>
          <label>Password</label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Please Choose A Password" formControlName="PW" size="25">
          <br>
          <label>Resubmit Your Password</label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Please Resubmit Your Password"
            formControlName="PWVerification" validateEqual="password" size="30">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!newUser.valid">
          <br>
          <span *ngIf="newUser.get('Email').invalid &&!newUser.get('Email').pristine">Your email does not look
            right</span>
          <br>
          <span *ngIf="newUser.get('Tz').errors?.maxlength ||newUser.get('Tz').errors?.minlength ">Your ID must contain
            9 digits</span>
          <br>
          <span *ngIf="newUser.get('PW').invalid&&!newUser.get('PW').pristine">Password must include at least one letter
            and one digit</span>
          <br>
          <span *ngIf="newUser.get('PWVerification').errors?.matchOther">Your submitted passwords don't match</span>
          <br>
          <span *ngIf="newUser.get('Tz').errors?.exists">This ID already exists</span>
        </form>

        <form [formGroup]="newUser2" *ngIf="verification!=false">
          <label>City</label>
          <br>
          <input list="City" name="City" formControlName="City" placeholder="Choose City">
          <datalist id="City">
            <option value="Jerusalem">
            <option value="Tel Aviv">
            <option value="Haifa">
            <option value="Rishon LeZion">
            <option value="Petach Tikva">
            <option value="Ashdod">
            <option value="Netanya">
            <option value="Be'er Sheva">
            <option value="Holon">
            <option value="Bnei Brak">
          </datalist>
          <br>
          <label>Street</label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Please Input Street for Delivery" formControlName="Street">
          <br>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name here" formControlName="FirstName">
          <br>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name here" formControlName="LastName">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!newUser2.valid" (click)="onSubmit2()">  
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

app.module.ts-

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import {NgbModule, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [NgbActiveModal],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.html-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>YoavOnlineShop</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

angular.json-

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "YoavOnlineShop": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/YoavOnlineShop",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "YoavOnlineShop:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "YoavOnlineShop:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "YoavOnlineShop:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "YoavOnlineShop:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "YoavOnlineShop:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "YoavOnlineShop"
}
```

package.json-

```
{
  "name": "yoav-online-shop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.9",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your **package.json** . It must contains the ng-bootstrap as dependency. Then at **angular.json** you have to provide the path to boostrap node module inside scripts array

Comment: Certainly. I'll edit the question above

Comment: Ok i'll post what i' m currently doing in my project for a similar use case

Answer (score 0):

Providing ng-bootstrap into **package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    ... // dependencies over here
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "xxx"

}
```

Then in **angular.json:**

```
 "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

I do not import any js into my **index.html**

Finally in my component i use NgbModalRef instead. I' m posting the whole components so sorry about the boilerplate code.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {ParamsService} from '../../services/params.service';
import {NgbModal, NgbModalRef} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {NgxSpinnerComponent, NgxSpinnerService} from 'ngx-spinner';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {UserService} from '../../services/user.service';
import {StudyDirection} from '../../model/direction.model';
import {forEach} from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-directions',
  templateUrl: './directions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./directions.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class DirectionsComponent implements OnInit {
  public directions: StudyDirection[];
  public direction: StudyDirection;
  public modalRef: NgbModalRef;
  public form: FormGroup;
  public tempDirection: StudyDirection;

  constructor(private paramService: ParamsService,
              private modalService: NgbModal,
              private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
              private userService: UserService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDirections();
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      code: [null, Validators.required],
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      description: null,
      parentDirectionid: null,

    });
  }

  getDirections() {
    this.paramService.getDirectionsList().subscribe(directions => {
      this.directions = directions;
    });
  }

  openAddModal(content) {
    this.direction = new StudyDirection();
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(content, {container: '.app'});

    this.modalRef.result.then((result) => {
      this.form.reset();
    }, (reason) => {
      this.form.reset();
    });
  }

  deleteDirection(direction) {
    this.spinner.show();
    this.paramService.removeDirection(direction).subscribe(response => {
      this.getDirections();
      this.spinner.hide();
    }, error => {
      this.spinner.hide();
    });
  }

  addDirection(directionid) {
    this.paramService.addDirection(directionid).subscribe(response => {
      this.getDirections();
      this.modalRef.close();


    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    console.log(directionid);
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.modalRef.close();
  }

}
```

The .app is a class on top of my theme. So my modal opened with:

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(content, {container: '.app'});
```

and then to close it:

```
this.modalRef.close();
```